# Browser scrolling breaks after animate/scrollTop is executed

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, scrolltop

I'm running into a weird problem with the browser/mouse scroll wheel breaks after animate is called. The only way to 'reset' it is to refresh the browser, and avoid the hover call. Basically, when I hover over the element, there is a scroll action. It works, but after that, my scroll wheel is not responding.

Here is my code snippet:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#product-home').hover(function(){
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#navigation").offset().top - 250
            }, 2000);
            return true;
        });

    });
</script>
```

Seems to recover in Firefox, but Chrome requires a fresh. I'm wondering if I need to reset scroll or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that `.hover()` with only one argument means `.hover(handlerInOut)`, i. e. your handler function will be called both on `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events. Try using `.mouseenter()` instead.

In Chrome this gives me better results - scrolling still freezes after animation, but only for a very short time. (Tested with a very simple webpage).

```
$(function() {
    $('#product-home').mouseenter(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#navigation").offset().top - 250
        }, 2000);
    return true;
});
```

Comment: Yes, that's much better. Thank you!